# Excel scatter chart with percentile lines

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I add percentile lines to a scatter chart in Excel?

This image is a crude drawing. Basically, for each range of x (horizontal) values, I want to calculate (and plot) the mean, the 25th, and the 75th percentiles of y values.

[image: Scatterplot with lines]

Below is a sample of some of the data used to generate this scatter chart.

```
18  0.4
17  1.6
17  -0.5
20  2.4
20  3.6
18  4.2
19  4.6
18  4.5
19  3.7
19  3.9
18  5.4
17  7.2
17  6.8
17  9.2
17  10.0
17  8.7
17  7.9
17  6.8
19  7.8
19  8.4
20  6.4
19  4.9
21  5.4
21  5.7
21  5.7
22  5.6
20  7.1
20  7.7
20  8.0
18  8.8
18  6.8
20  6.0
21  7.2
21  6.4
21  3.9
22  4.9
22  4.9
22  5.9
21  5.4
22  5.3
21  4.3
20  5.0
20  3.6
22  1.6
21  1.4
21  3.1
22  0.9
23  1.7
24  1.2
25  0.3
25  1.3
26  2.7
26  3.2
27  2.5
27  4.9
24  3.0
24  3.0
25  2.0
24  1.4
23  1.7
25  2.3
24  -0.1
25  1.2
24  2.7
24  4.0
24  1.6
24  1.0
24  0.3
24  0.8
23  0.1
24  -0.6
23  -1.9
23  -3.5
21  -4.0
21  -4.7
22  -2.6
21  -2.6
22  -0.8
22  -0.4
23  0.7
23  2.5
22  5.3
22  5.2
21  4.4
21  3.3
21  2.8
20  4.1
20  3.6
19  0.9
19  0.8
19  2.0
19  1.7
19  4.8
18  5.7
18  4.8
17  3.8
17  3.7
17  3.1
17  1.6
17  0.9
18  0.9
19  0.3
19  0.9
18  2.4
19  2.7
18  3.6
18  2.5
18  -0.7
19  0.7
18  1.4
19  0.8
19  0.3
19  -3.1
19  -5.1
19  -3.8
19  -3.6
19  -3.2
19  -4.6
18  -2.9
19  -3.4
19  -4.4
19  -3.4
19  -5.4
18  -6.5
18  -6.1
17  -6.6
18  -6.7
19  -3.3
19  -1.9
19  -2.5
19  -2.5
19  -2.2
20  1.1
21  4.1
21  4.5
21  4.3
22  4.6
21  4.7
20  3.5
20  4.7
20  4.9
20  4.2
19  5.0
19  7.8
19  7.1
20  7.1
19  7.7
19  5.3
20  5.5
20  7.2
20  5.7
20  4.8
19  2.9
18  1.5
19  -4.3
19  -6.3
18  -6.2
18  -6.3
18  -6.0
18  -7.0
18  -7.0
18  -6.1
18  -4.9
18  -6.5
18  -8.5
18  -8.2
19  -9.1
19  -6.9
19  -6.6
19  -7.8
20  -6.7
20  -5.4
19  -5.4
20  -4.2
24  0.3
28  2.1
26  1.7
25  1.6
23  3.1
24  3.1
24  2.9
23  0.4
23  0.1
23  0.0
25  3.2
25  2.6
25  3.9
25  3.4
25  3.1
25  4.2
26  4.4
25  4.7
26  5.0
25  4.2
25  4.2
24  4.4
25  4.3
24  5.0
22  3.3
22  1.5
21  2.4
21  3.1
21  0.4
21  0.6
21  1.2
20  3.2
20  3.6
20  3.7
20  3.2
20  2.3
19  2.1
19  3.3
19  3.1
18  2.6
18  2.2
18  2.2
18  1.3
18  1.6
18  0.6
19  1.8
19  1.5
19  2.8
20  4.6
19  3.8
19  3.2
19  1.2
18  -0.4
19  -0.6
19  -0.7
19  -1.8
19  -2.3
19  -4.7
20  -2.9
20  -0.3
21  0.6
20  1.7
21  3.2
21  3.1
21  4.9
21  5.1
21  5.8
20  6.2
20  7.6
20  9.1
19  7.7
19  7.7
19  11.2
18  9.5
19  9.2
18  11.9
18  13.2
19  13.2
19  11.2
18  9.6
18  9.2
18  9.5
18  9.3
17  8.2
17  6.9
17  5.8
17  5.7
20  3.8
20  5.0
20  6.0
22  6.1
22  6.6
23  4.2
25  4.5
25  4.9
26  3.7
25  2.7
26  3.6
25  3.3
23  2.8
24  4.6
23  3.9
24  3.4
24  2.9
24  4.6
24  5.5
24  4.9
24  5.2
23  3.0
23  2.4
24  2.6
24  3.0
24  4.4
24  6.7
23  6.6
23  5.8
23  6.4
23  4.2
23  2.2
22  2.7
22  1.3
22  1.1
20  3.4
20  4.7
20  2.0
20  2.4
20  0.6
20  0.9
20  -0.9
20  -4.6
20  -2.8
21  -2.4
22  -4.1
24  -2.7
24  -4.8
25  -4.5
24  -6.5
24  -4.8
24  -2.3
23  -2.4
23  -1.4
23  -1.9
23  -3.7
23  -2.2
23  -0.4
24  -0.9
26  0.2
26  -0.3
26  2.7
29  5.3
28  3.4
27  0.2
27  0.2
27  -4.6
28  -3.1
29  -2.3
30  0.2
31  2.6
31  2.2
29  2.2
28  0.6
28  0.6
27  -0.3
26  -0.6
26  -0.1
25  -0.4
25  1.1
27  2.0
27  1.4
26  1.6
25  2.5
25  5.5
25  6.3
27  9.0
26  9.9
25  9.6
25  9.7
24  6.7
23  6.3
23  6.3
23  5.9
22  6.2
23  5.4
23  3.2
23  3.6
23  3.9
21  3.6
22  3.7
22  3.4
22  3.2
22  2.0
21  2.5
21  1.9
21  2.6
22  2.9
21  1.4
21  -0.4
21  0.0
22  0.3
21  0.1
21  1.1
21  1.4
21  3.8
21  5.0
20  4.3
21  4.1
20  2.9
19  3.3
19  4.7
18  4.7
18  6.6
17  7.3
18  7.1
17  7.0
17  6.2
17  7.3
17  6.7
18  6.9
17  8.8
17  8.6
17  7.3
16  7.8
16  6.0
16  4.2
16  2.6
17  3.9
18  2.3
18  1.0
17  -0.6
17  -2.0
17  -4.4
21  -5.8
23  -4.6
22  -3.8
23  -3.3
22  -4.9
23  -4.4
22  -4.5
22  -6.0
21  -7.5
22  -4.1
22  -4.6
22  -4.4
23  -3.4
23  -1.2
22  -2.5
22  -0.5
24  1.8
23  2.5
24  3.6
24  1.8
24  1.5
23  -0.9
22  -3.4
22  -4.2
22  -1.0
23  -3.1
23  -5.4
22  -10.2
23  -27.6
23  -25.9
23  -19.6
23  -22.4
23  -22.5
22  -29.6
23  -27.5
22  -27.5
22  -25.2
21  -23.3
21  -22.0
24  -21.4
22  -21.8
24  -19.0
24  -19.5
25  -21.4
24  -24.0
26  -20.7
28  -16.6
36  -13.1
150 9.7
140 2.6
74  -5.0
102 -3.3
99  -2.5
113 6.7
98  5.7
81  4.6
65  -1.8
61  -8.5
55  -9.3
58  -6.9
58  -9.5
54  -12.0
56  -8.6
55  -3.4
55  0.0
56  -3.4
49  -5.3
48  -1.4
47  -1.6
50  2.1
47  -1.0
50  3.8
48  3.1
43  2.9
38  2.7
36  3.2
42  2.2
46  6.2
46  6.8
44  5.8
47  13.6
48  15.5
44  13.2
41  11.1
44  1.9
49  6.0
48  4.3
47  1.5
47  1.3
44  1.6
42  3.7
39  0.1
36  -2.8
36  -2.7
33  -2.6
32  0.1
39  1.6
38  2.0
36  2.2
39  4.0
36  -0.4
37  -1.2
37  -2.6
34  -3.4
49  3.1
41  0.7
41  2.6
42  4.4
42  4.1
36  2.2
35  3.2
36  4.0
40  6.3
40  7.6
38  7.8
36  5.1
36  6.0
37  4.9
36  3.6
36  4.2
37  4.8
36  4.9
39  6.2
38  6.0
38  6.5
38  8.2
34  6.9
35  2.8
37  3.5
34  3.4
33  2.4
32  3.6
32  5.2
28  3.6
28  1.2
30  1.4
30  1.7
32  0.7
32  -1.5
30  -3.6
30  -2.7
30  -3.7
30  -3.4
29  -4.2
28  -3.3
28  -1.5
28  -1.1
30  2.1
28  2.0
29  1.9
29  2.0
29  -3.3
27  -4.2
28  -4.4
28  -4.0
28  -4.7
27  -4.6
32  -1.2
34  1.5
32  2.3
32  1.4
32  1.8
27  0.9
31  2.1
29  1.7
25  -1.9
26  -2.8
25  -4.4
26  -5.0
26  -5.1
26  -6.7
31  -2.3
32  -1.2
28  -0.2
27  -1.0
29  -1.9
29  -1.5
28  -2.7
27  -4.4
25  -3.9
26  -3.8
27  -3.0
27  -3.0
26  0.2
25  1.4
27  1.9
28  3.0
27  3.7
26  3.4
25  5.4
28  6.7
27  6.9
26  5.7
25  6.0
25  7.5
27  7.3
27  7.2
26  6.3
25  8.3
25  8.7
24  8.3
24  7.5
24  6.2
23  3.9
25  1.6
25  3.1
25  2.0
25  3.3
25  2.6
25  0.1
26  -0.1
26  -0.3
27  -1.3
26  -1.8
26  -1.5
26  0.8
25  -0.1
24  -0.2
24  -0.6
24  -3.3
25  -4.1
25  -3.3
25  -1.4
25  -3.6
25  -1.8
25  -0.5
24  0.2
24  -1.4
25  0.4
24  0.1
25  0.4
23  -0.2
24  -0.5
23  -2.8
23  -2.8
20  -3.5
21  -4.4
24  -2.9
24  -3.4
25  -2.1
25  -1.2
25  -2.9
24  -3.1
24  -0.5
23  -2.6
23  -4.5
22  -3.6
22  -3.5
22  -4.2
23  -5.0
23  -2.5
23  -1.6
25  -0.2
27  1.5
25  1.6
25  1.5
28  3.4
26  3.4
25  2.8
24  3.7
24  3.3
26  5.0
25  5.1
23  3.1
23  4.1
22  3.5
21  2.3
21  2.5
21  4.2
23  5.2
21  2.6
21  1.9
21  2.3
21  2.4
20  4.2
20  4.4
20  3.9
20  1.7
19  2.6
18  1.8
19  2.8
19  3.6
19  2.5
19  5.1
18  5.2
19  5.0
19  5.3
19  4.6
18  1.7
19  2.4
18  2.8
19  3.1
19  2.6
20  2.5
19  -0.6
20  -1.5
19  -1.0
22  -0.2
20  -0.6
20  -2.8
20  -3.1
19  -4.0
21  -4.7
20  -6.5
20  -6.1
21  -5.7
21  -5.4
22  -4.4
24  -3.6
23  -3.6
23  -2.9
22  -1.9
23  -2.4
23  -2.6
23  -0.5
24  1.3
25  1.1
23  1.2
21  1.2
23  3.2
23  3.2
23  2.6
25  4.0
22  4.4
21  4.7
20  4.2
20  3.8
19  2.9
20  4.0
19  3.0
18  2.3
18  2.1
19  1.9
19  1.3
18  1.6
18  0.9
19  0.9
19  1.6
18  1.2
17  2.0
18  2.5
17  3.1
17  3.6
16  2.6
16  2.7
16  -0.9
16  -0.8
17  -1.1
18  0.1
18  0.9
17  0.3
17  0.9
18  0.8
18  -1.1
18  -1.8
19  -2.3
19  -1.4
19  -1.7
18  -2.4
17  -3.2
17  -1.9
17  -1.5
18  0.5
17  0.2
17  -1.0
17  0.0
17  -0.6
16  -0.4
17  -1.9
17  -1.4
17  -2.2
17  -2.3
17  -2.2
18  -1.2
18  -1.5
20  -0.7
20  0.1
19  -2.2
20  -2.4
20  -0.8
18  -0.4
18  -0.1
17  0.7
17  1.7
17  1.5
17  -0.3
17  0.1
16  0.2
16  1.0
16  0.3
16  1.2
16  1.5
16  2.1
16  2.7
17  3.0
17  3.8
17  2.8
19  4.7
20  5.4
18  3.8
17  3.5
17  2.5
16  1.0
15  -0.8
15  -1.4
16  0.6
17  1.5
16  1.4
16  0.2
16  1.2
16  0.7
16  0.7
16  1.1
16  0.1
17  1.2
17  -0.8
17  -0.5
17  -0.8
17  -0.6
16  -0.6
15  -2.0
16  -2.2
15  -1.8
15  -0.8
15  0.0
15  -1.1
14  -3.4
14  -3.5
14  -2.2
14  -2.6
15  -1.8
14  -2.0
14  -3.3
14  -2.9
14  -2.0
15  -1.3
14  -0.4
14  -0.4
15  0.1
15  -1.0
16  0.1
17  1.7
16  1.4
15  1.2
15  1.8
15  2.2
18  3.8
18  3.7
16  2.5
17  2.6
15  1.7
14  2.0
14  2.1
15  2.0
13  2.1
13  3.5
13  2.7
14  3.0
15  2.7
16  3.7
16  2.9
15  1.5
14  1.0
14  1.1
14  0.3
13  0.2
12  0.0
13  1.0
13  1.7
13  1.8
14  1.8
13  1.5
13  0.8
14  -0.2
13  -1.4
13  -2.1
14  -2.5
13  -2.2
14  -2.6
14  -2.0
14  -1.0
14  -0.6
14  -0.4
15  -1.2
15  -0.6
15  0.5
15  0.4
15  1.3
15  -0.2
14  -0.3
14  0.4
14  1.1
15  1.8
16  1.6
16  1.4
15  1.2
14  0.2
13  0.4
14  0.7
13  0.4
13  -0.4
13  -1.8
13  -2.3
14  -1.8
13  -2.9
13  -2.9
12  -4.0
13  -4.2
14  -2.5
15  -2.5
14  -2.5
14  -2.6
13  -1.7
14  -0.4
14  -0.4
13  -0.9
15  -0.1
15  0.4
15  0.4
14  0.6
16  1.1
18  2.0
20  3.7
20  3.1
21  3.2
19  2.6
21  3.7
19  2.7
18  2.3
18  3.1
17  3.2
17  2.6
17  1.4
17  0.9
17  1.7
16  2.1
16  3.0
16  1.7
16  2.2
16  2.2
15  2.2
16  3.0
17  1.9
17  2.4
16  3.1
15  3.3
15  4.2
14  4.4
14  4.1
14  2.9
14  2.6
15  2.5
15  2.8
15  2.9
15  3.0
14  4.2
14  3.3
13  3.6
13  2.7
13  2.5
13  2.1
13  1.5
13  1.9
13  1.4
12  1.3
12  0.5
12  -0.2
12  -1.4
13  -1.5
13  -0.8
12  -0.6
13  0.0
12  0.8
13  1.3
12  0.3
12  -1.4
12  -1.7
12  -1.1
12  -0.7
12  0.1
12  0.2
12  0.0
13  0.0
13  0.7
13  1.6
13  1.9
13  2.9
15  4.4
14  4.6
13  3.9
13  3.3
12  3.0
12  2.7
12  1.7
11  -0.7
12  -0.4
12  -0.3
12  -0.3
11  -0.2
11  -1.2
11  0.2
12  1.0
12  1.1
12  0.7
12  1.2
12  1.5
12  0.0
12  -0.8
13  1.3
13  1.5
13  2.5
13  1.7
13  0.5
12  1.5
16  4.0
16  3.5
16  4.6
15  3.7
15  3.1
15  3.2
15  1.6
14  1.9
13  1.0
14  2.0
12  0.9
13  0.5
13  0.7
14  -1.1
16  -2.7
14  -2.9
14  -3.0
14  -2.6
16  -0.3
15  -0.5
15  -0.6
15  0.0
14  -0.7
13  -0.6
14  -0.8
13  -1.1
12  -1.9
12  -3.1
12  -3.2
13  -2.8
12  -3.1
13  -2.8
13  -2.2
15  0.2
14  0.4
14  0.8
14  0.1
13  0.1
12  -1.2
12  -1.1
12  -0.9
11  -2.0
11  -2.1
12  -1.6
12  -1.1
12  0.9
13  2.5
13  2.0
15  3.3
14  2.5
13  3.5
13  3.1
12  2.3
13  2.6
12  2.2
12  1.8
13  1.5
13  1.2
14  0.4
13  0.3
14  0.1
15  1.8
14  1.9
14  1.3
14  1.6
14  0.2
14  -1.5
15  0.1
14  -0.5
14  -1.3
13  -1.5
13  -1.1
13  0.4
14  -0.7
13  -0.7
14  -0.8
13  -0.9
14  -1.4
15  -0.4
14  0.6
13  0.6
13  0.4
12  0.1
12  0.9
12  0.4
12  -0.6
12  0.5
12  0.2
12  0.3
12  0.3
12  0.1
11  0.3
11  -0.8
11  -0.8
11  -0.1
12  -0.2
11  1.0
14  1.8
13  1.3
12  -0.1
11  0.1
11  0.4
11  0.3
11  0.1
11  -0.1
11  1.0
11  1.4
11  1.3
12  2.0
12  2.7
11  2.0
11  1.4
11  2.6
11  2.9
11  2.4
12  2.8
11  2.6
11  3.2
12  3.3
12  2.9
12  2.8
12  1.7
12  1.6
12  1.6
12  2.8
12  2.6
12  1.7
12  1.9
12  0.7
12  0.5
12  -0.2
12  -0.5
12  -0.8
12  -0.5
12  -0.7
12  0.3
12  -0.1
12  -0.7
11  -0.9
12  0.0
11  0.0
13  0.6
13  0.9
13  0.4
12  -0.3
12  -0.3
13  0.3
13  0.0
13  1.6
13  2.3
15  2.9
17  2.9
14  2.2
13  1.7
12  1.2
12  0.5
12  0.6
13  1.0
13  1.9
12  1.4
13  1.7
13  1.6
13  0.5
13  -0.4
12  -0.2
12  -0.1
12  -0.2
11  0.5
11  -0.9
11  -0.9
11  -1.0
12  0.1
11  -0.3
11  -0.4
11  -0.1
12  -1.1
12  -0.7
12  -0.5
12  -1.0
11  -1.3
12  -1.6
12  -1.4
13  0.0
15  1.6
15  1.5
14  1.4
14  1.3
14  0.1
14  0.3
13  0.1
14  -0.1
15  -1.0
16  -0.3
15  0.6
15  0.7
16  1.3
14  1.4
14  1.1
14  1.6
14  2.0
14  1.9
14  1.5
14  0.7
13  0.1
13  0.1
12  0.2
12  0.2
12  1.2
13  2.4
11  1.8
11  2.4
11  2.3
11  2.5
11  1.5
11  1.8
10  1.9
9   1.6
9   1.6
10  0.3
10  0.0
10  0.6
11  1.8
12  2.6
13  3.5
12  2.7
11  3.1
11  2.9
11  0.0
11  -0.7
11  -0.6
12  -0.3
12  -0.7
11  -1.0
12  -0.6
12  -0.4
12  -0.3
11  -1.0
11  -1.5
12  -0.1
11  0.0
11  -1.9
10  -2.3
10  -2.4
11  -3.6
11  -3.1
11  -3.9
11  -3.3
15  -0.6
14  -1.2
14  -0.8
13  -1.9
14  -0.5
14  -0.6
14  -0.7
13  -0.7
13  -0.4
14  0.2
15  0.2
14  -0.6
14  -0.5
16  0.0
15  -1.2
15  -1.5
16  -2.6
16  -4.1
16  -3.7
16  -5.6
14  -4.0
16  -3.8
14  -3.5
17  -3.6
15  -3.6
17  -4.2
15  -4.4
15  -4.9
13  -5.2
13  -6.1
14  -5.5
13  -5.7
12  -4.2
13  -3.6
14  -1.7
15  -1.8
16  -0.7
19  1.2
20  1.6
24  3.2
18  0.8
17  0.7
17  -0.7
17  -1.1
17  -0.9
16  -1.4
17  -0.6
16  -0.5
16  -0.4
17  1.6
17  2.5
17  3.3
15  1.4
15  1.2
14  0.5
14  1.0
15  1.8
14  1.4
14  0.8
14  1.0
14  1.3
15  1.9
15  2.5
16  3.6
15  2.5
16  3.7
15  3.4
15  3.4
15  4.0
14  2.5
13  1.8
12  0.4
13  0.1
13  -0.4
13  -0.4
12  -1.5
13  -3.1
12  -2.2
13  -2.3
13  -2.2
13  -2.9
12  -3.0
13  -2.7
13  -2.6
13  -1.9
13  -1.8
13  -2.3
12  -2.4
12  -3.0
12  -1.6
11  -1.7
12  -0.7
14  -0.4
15  0.1
14  -0.1
14  0.8
17  2.6
16  1.4
15  1.5
14  1.5
15  3.1
14  3.3
15  3.2
15  3.4
14  2.2
13  1.7
14  2.2
13  2.2
12  2.6
12  1.2
11  1.7
11  1.3
12  2.5
12  3.0
12  2.3
11  2.3
11  1.8
12  2.5
12  3.6
12  3.0
11  3.4
11  2.9
11  3.4
11  3.0
12  3.2
12  3.0
12  3.1
13  2.9
12  2.8
12  2.0
11  0.9
12  1.4
11  0.8
12  2.1
12  1.7
13  1.5
13  0.2
12  -0.7
12  -1.7
12  -1.8
12  -2.7
12  -2.6
11  -2.4
12  -2.8
12  -2.2
11  -2.0
12  -3.7
12  -3.7
12  -4.4
13  -2.8
14  -1.5
14  -0.4
13  -0.7
12  -1.5
13  -0.4
13  -0.4
14  0.9
14  1.9
14  1.2
15  1.1
15  0.0
14  -0.1
13  -0.5
14  0.8
14  2.4
15  2.3
17  3.0
16  2.9
16  3.4
15  1.6
15  0.9
14  0.0
15  0.0
15  -0.7
13  -1.4
15  -0.6
15  -0.6
15  -1.0
16  -0.7
16  -0.7
17  -0.5
16  -2.5
16  -2.7
16  -2.9
15  -4.1
15  -3.6
15  -3.1
15  -3.8
16  -3.1
17  -1.9
17  -2.2
16  -3.1
16  -4.3
16  -3.7
17  -2.8
17  -3.4
17  -2.2
16  -2.2
16  -1.0
16  -0.8
16  -0.3
17  2.1
18  2.2
17  1.7
17  1.8
16  1.3
16  1.6
17  2.3
17  1.3
16  1.6
16  1.6
16  2.1
18  3.5
16  3.3
15  2.7
14  2.6
13  2.4
13  3.1
13  2.5
13  2.6
13  2.2
12  1.1
12  1.3
12  1.3
12  1.1
13  1.6
13  2.0
13  2.0
14  2.5
14  2.1
14  2.7
13  3.9
13  4.4
13  4.1
12  4.2
13  4.0
11  3.3
11  2.6
12  2.7
12  3.2
12  3.9
12  3.7
13  3.6
12  4.1
11  4.2
11  4.2
11  2.9
12  4.0
12  3.2
12  3.1
11  2.7
11  1.5
11  0.2
11  0.5
11  0.4
12  2.0
11  1.8
11  2.3
11  1.9
12  2.2
12  2.1
12  2.9
12  2.6
11  2.2
11  1.9
11  2.6
13  4.0
12  3.4
12  3.6
12  3.5
11  3.1
12  3.3
14  4.8
14  4.6
13  4.7
12  3.4
12  3.5
12  2.6
12  3.1
12  2.8
12  2.1
11  1.9
12  2.0
11  1.9
11  2.5
11  2.4
12  1.8
11  1.7
13  2.1
13  2.5
13  2.7
14  2.6
13  3.0
13  3.0
13  2.8
13  3.5
13  3.3
13  3.7
12  3.4
11  3.2
12  4.3
13  4.5
13  4.4
12  2.8
12  2.1
12  2.1
12  3.2
12  3.1
12  2.9
12  1.7
12  1.8
12  3.6
12  2.5
13  2.3
12  3.0
12  2.2
13  1.8
13  1.5
13  0.7
12  1.0
12  1.6
12  1.6
12  1.9
13  3.9
13  5.0
12  4.1
12  2.9
11  4.2
12  4.0
12  3.9
13  3.6
13  2.1
12  1.9
13  2.3
13  2.1
13  2.2
13  3.9
13  4.5
13  5.5
12  4.5
11  4.6
11  4.6
11  4.2
11  4.2
11  2.4
11  1.1
11  1.8
11  0.5
11  1.3
12  3.1
12  3.5
12  3.8
12  3.5
11  3.2
12  2.3
12  2.1
12  0.9
12  0.5
12  0.5
12  1.0
12  -0.2
13  -0.6
12  -0.9
12  -0.5
13  0.0
13  1.6
13  1.0
12  1.0
13  0.3
13  -0.3
13  -0.8
13  -1.4
13  -0.5
13  -0.5
14  0.1
14  0.4
14  0.6
13  0.9
13  1.6
13  1.7
13  1.9
13  2.7
13  3.4
13  3.0
12  3.6
12  4.2
12  4.3
12  4.2
13  4.7
13  4.9
13  4.6
13  4.4
12  3.9
12  4.0
13  3.8
12  4.4
12  4.0
11  3.2
12  2.3
12  2.0
12  2.2
11  1.7
12  0.8
11  0.2
11  0.1
11  -0.1
12  0.2
12  0.0
13  0.4
12  0.1
13  1.3
12  1.0
13  0.6
13  0.9
13  0.2
12  -1.6
13  -0.8
14  0.3
15  -0.1
15  0.5
16  1.2
14  1.4
15  1.7
15  1.5
15  2.1
14  1.7
14  1.4
15  1.6
14  0.4
14  1.1
14  1.1
13  2.1
14  2.0
14  2.3
14  2.7
16  4.0
15  3.7
14  4.0
14  4.5
13  3.6
13  2.9
12  3.9
13  5.0
13  5.8
12  4.1
12  4.1
13  4.5
13  4.5
13  5.5
13  3.9
13  3.2
12  1.1
12  2.5
12  0.9
12  2.0
12  2.0
12  2.2
12  1.3
12  1.1
12  1.7
11  2.3
11  1.2
12  0.0
13  -0.6
13  0.4
11  -1.3
11  -3.4
11  -2.6
10  -3.2
11  -2.8
11  -1.3
15  -0.1
13  -0.6
12  1.0
11  0.5
12  0.1
11  0.9
12  0.4
12  1.2
13  1.3
12  1.5
12  2.4
14  3.4
14  3.1
13  3.7
15  6.1
16  8.6
15  8.9
14  9.1
15  10.3
14  8.6
14  8.1
14  7.1
13  5.9
13  4.4
14  5.8
13  6.3
13  6.8
12  4.6
12  3.7
12  2.3
13  0.7
13  0.9
13  2.4
13  2.2
15  0.9
14  0.6
14  -3.4
15  -2.5
15  -3.7
15  -3.3
16  -2.2
16  -1.5
15  0.7
17  1.7
14  0.3
15  -1.5
15  -1.3
16  -0.1
17  0.9
17  0.6
17  1.3
17  0.2
17  0.4
16  -0.1
17  0.6
16  0.3
21  1.7
19  0.3
19  -0.6
18  -1.2
17  -0.6
17  0.2
17  -1.2
18  -1.5
19  -1.0
18  -0.6
17  -0.4
18  0.2
18  -0.4
18  0.6
18  0.7
19  1.3
18  0.1
16  -0.1
16  -1.9
16  -2.2
19  -0.5
17  -0.6
20  1.8
20  2.3
17  2.4
17  3.0
16  3.2
17  3.7
16  3.3
15  3.7
15  3.9
15  3.3
15  4.3
15  3.5
15  3.8
15  2.8
16  2.1
16  2.6
19  4.0
17  4.1
17  5.0
17  6.3
16  4.4
17  4.3
16  3.1
15  1.4
15  0.5
16  0.4
16  0.2
15  -0.6
16  -1.6
16  -1.6
16  -2.4
16  -1.4
16  -1.4
17  -0.6
17  -0.5
16  -0.5
16  0.2
17  1.2
16  0.2
16  -0.9
17  -2.3
16  -3.1
17  -2.6
17  -2.2
17  -3.5
17  -3.3
19  -5.4
17  -5.5
17  -4.2
18  -2.8
17  -3.5
16  -5.0
16  -6.3
15  -6.3
15  -5.0
14  -4.9
14  -5.9
14  -6.0
14  -5.0
14  -3.3
16  0.8
16  1.2
15  1.2
16  1.2
18  2.6
17  2.5
20  5.7
20  5.1
19  4.4
18  2.9
17  4.1
20  5.2
22  6.2
21  6.1
19  6.3
17  4.9
20  5.2
21  4.9
19  3.9
19  1.1
16  -1.6
17  -0.8
17  -1.0
16  -2.2
16  -1.0
16  0.3
16  -0.3
16  1.1
16  1.4
15  2.8
15  2.8
15  2.5
15  2.4
15  2.7
14  2.4
14  2.9
15  3.3
15  2.9
15  3.2
16  4.4
17  5.4
18  5.2
19  5.9
21  6.7
17  7.0
16  6.0
16  5.5
16  4.4
16  3.5
15  3.0
15  2.9
16  2.9
16  3.4
16  3.5
16  3.5
16  3.4
16  3.1
16  3.1
16  2.4
16  2.1
17  1.4
17  1.8
17  1.0
17  1.8
15  0.3
15  0.5
16  1.9
16  4.0
16  4.8
15  4.3
15  4.0
16  3.8
16  3.8
15  4.1
15  3.8
16  3.8
16  5.0
16  5.2
17  5.8
17  6.8
18  8.6
18  7.8
18  7.7
18  7.3
18  7.5
18  5.9
18  4.3
17  2.7
17  1.6
16  2.6
14  2.1
15  1.5
15  -0.3
14  -1.0
14  -2.3
15  -1.5
15  -1.4
16  0.2
16  0.8
15  -0.2
16  -0.8
17  0.0
17  0.2
17  -0.4
18  -2.1
19  -1.5
18  0.4
18  0.4
19  1.8
18  -0.2
18  1.0
20  2.5
20  4.1
21  5.5
22  6.4
21  6.0
19  6.1
19  4.1
19  4.5
20  5.3
19  3.5
19  1.9
19  1.1
20  1.5
21  4.3
21  6.4
19  5.1
20  5.2
19  4.8
20  4.0
21  3.4
20  4.0
20  3.4
19  2.7
19  4.6
20  5.5
19  4.2
19  5.1
18  3.8
17  2.1
18  3.1
19  5.2
20  6.1
21  5.3
20  2.9
19  0.8
19  1.2
20  0.5
19  1.6
21  2.6
20  3.2
19  3.1
21  3.3
20  1.9
19  -1.6
19  -2.3
19  -1.6
20  -3.3
21  -3.3
21  -2.5
21  -2.2
20  -2.4
20  -2.8
21  -1.9
21  -2.7
21  -4.3
21  -4.5
21  -5.2
19  -6.4
20  -5.1
19  -5.3
19  -5.8
19  -6.3
20  -5.7
20  -6.6
20  -6.2
21  -5.2
21  -3.3
22  -3.1
21  -2.1
20  -3.0
20  -2.1
19  -2.0
18  -2.4
21  -1.1
22  2.1
21  4.5
21  6.8
21  6.4
19  7.3
19  8.9
18  8.0
19  7.2
19  8.2
20  11.8
19  12.6
18  10.4
18  9.5
19  10.5
19  8.3
20  9.6
20  8.7
20  8.5
21  8.4
21  10.7
21  9.9
20  6.7
20  5.3
20  6.2
18  4.1
20  1.8
21  1.5
21  3.4
21  4.6
20  4.6
20  3.3
21  4.4
21  5.7
20  6.1
22  7.7
21  7.3
19  5.6
19  7.0
19  7.5
18  3.7
19  5.5
19  4.9
19  4.7
19  4.6
21  4.6
20  5.4
20  7.6
20  8.7
19  6.3
19  6.5
19  4.9
19  5.1
19  3.8
19  2.8
20  3.6
20  4.7
20  4.8
20  1.9
20  1.6
21  6.3
21  4.5
22  5.8
22  6.2
21  5.5
22  6.5
21  6.9
20  5.6
18  3.3
19  4.2
19  3.7
20  5.8
20  4.1
19  1.8
20  2.0
19  0.1
19  -1.6
21  -0.7
22  -1.6
24  0.0
22  -0.9
21  0.3
21  -1.6
21  -1.6
22  -1.7
22  -3.1
21  -4.1
21  -5.3
22  -5.0
22  -2.4
21  -2.6
20  -3.1
20  -2.3
22  -0.3
23  -0.4
24  -0.8
25  -1.0
23  -0.1
24  2.1
24  3.6
23  1.8
21  0.8
24  2.8
25  3.5
24  3.5
25  3.4
24  2.6
25  4.6
25  6.0
25  2.1
25  3.0
25  3.2
24  3.9
24  4.5
24  5.3
25  6.0
26  6.4
25  4.7
26  5.3
24  2.6
24  2.4
23  0.8
23  -0.7
22  0.0
22  2.1
23  2.5
23  1.4
22  -0.4
22  -8.0
23  -2.7
22  -3.8
22  -5.9
22  -5.2
22  -3.5
20  -4.3
21  -3.2
22  -3.4
20  -4.1
20  -4.9
20  -4.8
20  -6.2
21  -4.0
22  -1.7
21  -1.0
20  -3.5
20  -2.5
23  0.9
23  2.3
31  7.9
31  3.1
34  3.5
38  5.7
35  6.6
32  3.5
32  3.8
32  3.2
33  4.9
36  5.9
37  5.9
36  5.0
38  5.4
37  4.0
34  3.8
32  2.3
32  2.9
30  1.1
27  -1.3
27  -1.0
30  -0.8
29  -1.9
29  -1.6
27  -0.2
26  -0.4
26  -0.1
24  -0.2
24  0.4
23  -1.7
23  -1.9
23  -2.0
25  -4.3
28  -1.6
28  -0.1
27  -0.6
26  -1.8
26  -0.4
27  2.4
29  2.5
29  1.0
30  2.0
30  2.6
29  3.5
27  2.5
24  1.5
24  1.0
23  2.7
24  3.0
26  4.2
25  4.1
26  5.9
29  9.0
28  8.5
25  7.1
24  6.9
23  7.3
22  6.4
22  5.5
23  5.9
23  7.4
23  8.4
24  7.7
22  7.6
22  7.3
22  6.5
21  6.9
21  5.1
21  4.1
21  2.8
21  5.2
21  3.9
22  5.3
21  4.9
20  4.9
20  4.3
20  5.8
21  5.6
20  5.2
20  6.0
19  6.3
19  5.5
19  7.3
19  5.7
19  5.0
19  4.4
19  4.4
19  4.7
20  5.8
21  8.2
19  6.3
20  6.6
19  4.3
19  3.1
18  3.8
19  3.8
19  3.4
19  3.6
18  2.1
18  3.0
19  2.2
20  2.8
21  2.3
23  1.6
23  0.6
23  -0.8
25  -0.8
24  -0.6
23  0.3
22  0.1
22  -0.1
22  -0.5
24  -0.4
23  -0.6
22  -0.2
23  -0.3
22  0.0
21  0.0
22  0.8
21  -1.2
20  -1.6
20  -1.5
19  -1.0
21  -0.4
22  0.2
26  0.7
24  0.7
23  0.3
21  -1.9
19  -2.7
20  -2.6
21  -2.9
23  -0.9
23  1.7
21  0.7
21  1.1
21  -0.3
20  -2.2
20  -1.7
20  -2.9
22  -1.6
20  -0.2
20  -1.1
19  -1.3
19  -0.7
22  2.3
23  3.7
21  2.9
21  3.9
23  4.4
22  3.7
23  6.1
21  4.7
20  3.9
21  3.5
21  4.3
21  4.2
24  6.4
23  6.0
26  9.3
25  8.0
23  6.9
22  7.3
22  7.6
22  5.6
20  4.0
20  0.6
20  1.0
19  1.2
20  -0.7
20  -0.8
18  -0.5
18  -2.2
19  -3.9
19  -7.1
18  -7.3
18  -5.9
18  -6.4
18  -7.0
18  -9.2
18  -7.7
17  -9.2
16  -10.4
17  -8.5
20  -5.5
20  -5.7
23  -4.2
23  -5.2
23  -5.2
25  -3.3
25  -3.6
23  -8.8
25  -8.3
26  -13.9
31  -7.3
30  -8.4
28  -9.9
27  -10.6
29  -5.5
32  -5.9
29  -9.6
30  -6.1
34  -3.1
32  -4.2
28  -5.1
29  -7.2
30  -6.6
33  -5.3
32  -5.4
30  -2.4
31  -3.8
39  0.2
40  2.1
44  9.6
36  2.3
37  -0.4
41  2.1
43  1.5
38  -3.8
40  -3.5
45  -2.1
44  -2.4
39  -3.1
37  -4.1
36  -3.8
39  2.8
39  3.6
39  3.8
37  3.3
32  0.4
35  3.4
35  2.5
35  2.3
36  1.6
41  5.0
43  10.1
40  9.6
43  12.4
41  12.8
44  15.2
46  18.2
42  15.9
40  13.3
40  13.4
39  11.5
33  6.7
35  6.6
33  6.9
33  7.1
33  7.0
32  6.9
32  8.7
32  10.8
33  11.0
32  11.1
30  9.8
28  5.9
27  5.7
28  5.4
27  2.8
26  3.8
26  4.1
28  4.5
28  4.9
28  3.9
29  4.4
29  1.4
29  2.4
28  2.0
27  3.1
26  3.1
22  3.4
22  1.3
23  3.9
22  3.3
22  2.8
26  6.7
25  4.8
25  5.0
29  6.8
25  5.8
25  7.1
26  7.5
26  7.7
27  8.5
28  6.3
31  8.2
29  4.2
30  7.0
28  6.1
25  5.8
24  2.7
23  1.8
20  0.4
21  2.1
24  1.4
22  1.9
23  3.9
24  3.6
26  2.8
24  2.2
23  -1.9
24  -2.4
23  -2.5
25  -3.8
28  -1.3
30  1.6
33  1.5
29  -0.1
29  -2.2
29  -1.5
31  0.3
32  3.8
31  3.0
29  0.1
30  0.1
28  -2.1
26  -3.4
28  -3.7
28  -2.7
28  -2.0
29  2.2
30  3.5
30  2.9
31  5.8
30  6.1
27  3.2
30  6.3
30  5.2
31  6.0
30  6.4
29  4.8
26  2.0
26  -0.7
27  1.2
28  3.6
28  3.6
28  6.0
29  6.1
29  4.8
27  3.8
24  3.6
25  2.7
25  3.7
25  4.4
24  3.9
25  4.9
25  3.3
25  1.7
26  1.9
24  0.2
24  -0.8
25  0.7
27  5.9
27  7.1
24  5.2
24  6.0
24  4.0
23  3.9
23  4.4
22  3.2
22  2.5
23  1.1
23  1.5
23  -0.9
22  -0.2
22  -1.3
23  0.4
25  2.7
24  3.4
24  1.4
26  3.9
25  2.1
23  0.6
23  -1.5
23  -2.0
24  -3.9
23  -5.8
24  -3.4
25  -4.6
25  -2.5
24  -4.5
26  -2.8
25  -3.5
27  -0.3
25  -0.8
27  -1.7
26  -2.7
26  -4.5
25  -5.4
27  -3.3
27  -2.9
27  -0.2
25  -0.3
24  0.3
24  1.4
28  2.2
29  3.8
28  0.8
28  2.6
25  2.3
27  4.4
26  6.0
26  6.3
23  4.8
24  4.0
24  6.0
24  5.7
25  7.7
26  8.2
27  7.7
26  7.5
22  6.0
22  5.9
22  4.8
22  2.1
22  3.2
21  2.1
23  3.1
22  2.5
23  2.4
23  1.0
21  -2.3
20  -3.8
19  -4.5
21  -4.8
20  -6.5
20  -5.8
18  -7.3
20  -7.2
20  -8.0
20  -6.9
19  -7.9
17  -6.4
19  -5.5
22  -2.4
21  -3.4
23  -2.7
23  -1.5
25  0.9
23  0.0
23  1.2
25  1.6
25  1.5
26  -0.3
26  -0.1
27  2.0
27  0.4
27  4.4
28  4.1
28  4.9
25  3.5
25  4.1
22  1.2
23  0.4
22  -1.9
23  -1.1
24  0.9
23  -0.1
23  -3.9
22  -3.9
21  -7.3
21  -6.2
22  -4.8
25  -3.2
24  -3.9
23  -3.6
25  -2.8
21  -3.9
23  -3.6
24  -1.4
23  -2.2
22  -1.2
23  -0.7
24  -1.7
25  -2.5
25  -2.7
23  -6.6
24  -6.1
26  -3.5
25  -1.6
28  0.2
28  1.9
26  0.8
26  0.0
26  2.2
25  4.7
25  6.2
24  3.8
25  3.6
22  2.2
24  3.4
20  2.6
21  3.1
23  4.0
26  6.8
26  7.6
29  11.9
28  11.2
27  12.6
24  9.4
24  11.0
22  9.2
24  9.8
24  9.6
24  9.3
21  5.5
22  3.3
22  2.6
23  3.7
23  4.0
23  5.2
22  3.9
22  2.3
23  2.8
22  2.5
22  2.6
22  1.4
23  0.6
21  -0.5
21  0.6
20  -0.3
19  -0.3
20  0.9
21  2.2
20  2.9
22  2.9
24  3.5
24  5.4
22  4.8
22  4.3
19  1.5
21  -1.7
21  -0.5
21  0.0
21  2.4
21  2.9
22  1.6
23  2.1
22  2.6
22  3.3
21  2.4
24  2.7
23  0.8
22  0.4
21  -3.9
23  -3.2
23  -3.7
23  -4.4
25  -7.1
25  -5.1
24  -3.2
27  0.7
26  1.6
26  1.5
22  -1.2
22  -1.1
23  -1.9
23  -1.1
22  -4.3
20  -5.1
22  -3.6
22  -4.7
22  -4.0
21  -6.6
24  -3.5
23  -3.5
23  -3.6
24  -4.7
26  -0.9
25  -2.0
23  -2.1
23  -1.9
22  -1.1
22  -2.3
23  -4.8
21  -5.2
23  -0.7
23  -1.5
24  -0.3
24  -2.2
23  -0.7
24  5.1
23  5.5
26  8.2
26  10.5
24  10.3
24  12.9
25  14.6
25  13.0
23  10.3
22  9.4
21  7.7
19  6.3
22  8.2
24  10.3
24  8.8
22  7.1
21  8.7
23  8.7
24  10.4
22  5.4
21  -1.2
22  -7.4
23  -3.8
22  -3.5
21  -4.9
22  -6.1
23  -6.4
25  -3.0
25  -3.1
24  -2.9
25  -2.4
24  -2.0
24  -4.0
27  -5.3
28  -5.2
27  -4.6
24  -6.1
26  -6.1
27  -7.8
29  -4.0
29  -1.4
33  7.1
29  4.6
26  0.4
27  0.7
26  -1.9
27  -2.0
25  -7.0
27  -4.2
26  -5.7
26  -5.1
26  -3.1
29  -1.8
32  2.4
31  4.8
28  2.4
28  2.4
29  4.2
30  5.7
28  3.5
26  1.8
25  1.2
24  0.3
24  2.1
24  1.9
25  5.6
26  5.4
26  7.7
24  3.8
25  4.3
24  5.6
24  2.0
24  2.4
22  -0.4
21  -1.5
23  0.1
23  -0.8
22  -1.0
23  1.2
22  1.3
18  -3.6
16  -4.9
16  -9.0
15  -10.0
19  -4.2
18  -7.6
16  -5.1
15  -9.3
15  -11.2
15  -17.5
15  -14.0
15  -18.4
14  -26.6
14  -19.6
14  -29.4
15  -25.0
14  -29.2
16  -28.6
17  -30.9
25  -30.6
```

Comment: Unlike statistical packages that have features like these built-in, I think excel can only plot the trendline. The workaround would be to build data points for the 25- and 75- precentiles and plot it on the same graph (using different series).

Comment: @gns100: Which statistical package would you recommend for maximum productivity?

Comment: 10+ years ago the leading two were SAS/STAT and SPSS. I don't know if that has changed over the years. University (students and faculty) editions were low to no cost, but commercial licenses are costly. Good luck.

Comment: You might be able to use powerBI to also do this but I haven't tried it (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-analytics-pane#using-the-analytics-pane)